# Open node (internal link) in new tab

Tags: 7, views, nodes, navigation

How can I configure programmatically a node object to open in a new tab? I thought maybe in the `$node->path` array?

[image]

I don't see where and how I can achieve this... There is nothing such as a rendered `<a>` on which I can add a `target="_blank"`.

**EDIT (more specific situation):**

I've got a content type "news". It is possible to create news in 2 different ways:

- An editor user creates **manually** through the admin interface (basic).
- A **custom module imports data** from external RSS feeds everytime a piece of news is published in it.

I've got a **view** that display the **list of news** (just title, truncated text, date, logo...). When you click on a news' title, you access the full node view (normal). If it is an internal news (created manually), it displays normally. If it is an **imported news**, however, I **redirect** using drupal_goto to the source of the news (that I saved on node creation).

I want to make this very redirection **in a new tab**. It's quite complicated because it is originally an internal link (node/nid) that redirects to an external link (http://www.sourcesite.com).

I can make the difference between an imported/not imported node in the `hook_preprocess_views_view`. But I can't assign it something like a target _blank or whatever it exists to make this node opened in a new tab.

Comment: Seems that there is a serial downvoter this morning... Please leave a comment and justify why I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to which links should open like that? Every link to a node anywhere on the site, including user-generated content? Just one particular page/view/block? Only nodes of a certain content type?

Comment: I tried to be more specific in my edit, @Andy

Comment: I have a solution in mind: is it ok/good if the logic gets used anywhere a news node in teaser form is shown on the site (ie it's not restricted to the one view)?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 places in the site where this view appears and I'd like to achieve that for both places, so I guess it's ok! Summary: everytime I've got this view with imported news, I want them to be opened in a new tab.

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm you _can't_ do this in JS right?

Comment: Actually, I can open the new tab and set the focus on it in JS but, according to the SEO specialist, I have to achieve the redirect in PHP (drupal_goto) and not in JS. He needs to track I-don't-know-what that he can't if I use JS :-D

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand you. In order to open the link in a new window we modify its target attribute. This can be in the initial markup sent, or added later by JS. Generally folk prefer it to be added by JS (but I gave an answer showing how to do it server-side because I thought it was a requirement). There is no real _redirect_ going on unless I've missed something. Should I modify my answer to show a JS method?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the view? What happens when the "fake" node is accessed directly?

Comment: Don't worry about being downvoted ... and know that downvoting questions doesn't cost any reputation for the downvoter. Moreover, 1 upvote (like mine here ...) compensates for 2,5 downvotes, right? PS: feel free to re-enter the first few lines I just removed (cfr my comments why I did so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieve what I wanted. I succeed to access the info (hidden very deeply) in my `template.php` file within the following hook:

```
function pwe_2014_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  if(isset($vars['view']) && $vars['view']->name == "pwe_news") {
    foreach($vars['view']->result as $key => $result) {
      if(isset($result->node_feeds_item_nid) && ! is_null($result->node_feeds_item_nid)) {
        $vars['view']->result[$key]->class = "external";
      } else {
        $vars['view']->result[$key]->class = "internal";
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I assigned that new class to a new div in my `views-view-fields.tpl.php`:

```
<div class="<?php echo $row->class ?>">
...
</div>
```

And target that class with JavaScript:

```
$('.view-pwe-news .views-row .external a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Not easy to find the right theme function where I could access the right info.

Comment: In case you didn't try/know, devel themer can help you identify what template/theme function is responsible for particular markup, which can be very useful for nested templates like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a theming question and there's a choice to be made about whether to use a Views or a node template. By and large when displaying entities in views, I tend to use a particular view mode, because then I can display them similarly outside of Views if necessary. To do that:

1. Choose which view mode to use. In your case use the *Teaser* view mode, or if that's not an option create a new one.
2. Ensure your view's configured to display that view mode. 
   For more info, download and install advanced_help, and read from the Views help at least *Row styles* and its children *Fields* and *Node*.
3. Check in the node template you're using: is there a variable that would let you add a target attribute to the title link? (There isn't in core [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) but there might be in your theme.) For more info you can read [Overriding themable output](https://www.drupal.org/node/341628) and [Core templates and suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089662). I'd suggest using devel_themer to see what template is actually used - *make sure you've done step 2 first*. The template should either be `node.tpl.php` or start with `node--` and end `.tpl.php`.
4. If there wasn't a variable in step 3, then modify the template to have one, eg. by adding `$title_link_attributes`.
5. Implement `hook_preprocess_node()`. *Check if the node is of the correct type and view mode* and modify the variable appropriately. (And if you created a new variable, ensure that you set it to the empty string for other view modes and content types to avoid warnings.) For more info, see [Setting up variables for use in a template (preprocess and process functions)](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430).

Let me know if you have any questions, or if that approach isn't appropriate for any reason.

Btw I gave a non-JS answer because I thought that was a requirement, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: I'm going to test that solution first and I'll come back to you if I need it. Thank you anyway for your time!

Comment: Uhh... I can't access the information I need in the template part of the code. I guess I'm gonna explain the SEO guy that I have truly no choice but doing that in JS like I had. Well thanks a lot for trying to help! It's very kind of you.

Comment: @Djouuuuh You can't use the node object?

Comment: node object is empty (ofc) in views-view-list-pwe-news.tpl.php where I should add a variable or a class to target with my JS. I'm afraid I can't, indeed.

Comment: @Djouuuuh You're trying a different approach, using Views templates rather than node. It can be made to work, but as explained above I tend to do it differently.

Comment: If I could access to node object, I could test if it is an imported/not imported news in my views-view-list-pwe-news.tpl.php template and add a class to the <li> or something and then target all the $("li.external a") to add a "_blank" attribute. Have a look at the block and all the links leading to the content and that should have the target _blank: http://awesomescreenshot.com/05034c8192

Comment: @Djouuuuh I understood that, but you're not following the approach I described above. Specifically you're using a Views template (views-view-list-pwe-news.tpl.php) rather than a node one. Is there some reason you don't want to use a node template?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still quite new to Drupal and in my mind, a node template, as node.tpl.php, only proceed in the full page node view and not in a Views. I did not know it wasn't like that. You're telling me that if I use something like node--news.tpl.php, I can test the imported thing, set a variable like $link_title_attribute, do the test of this variable in hook_preprocess_node (is that hook called by Views to display the list of nodes? I guess it's quite logic, indeed ^^), and voilà? :-)

Comment: @Djouuuuh I've added some links with more details on the concepts in the answer.